# Unable to remove InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, android

I know that this exception is thrown when there are two classes with same name in different packages.

But in this case,I cannot understand how this exception is thrown upon encountering this statement (as seen in LogCat)

`s=tv2.getText().toString();` where s is String, ofcourse.

So,please help me in removing the problem.

These are the imports which I have used -

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Thanking you in anticipation.

Edit : LogCat Details

```
04-30 15:46:53.373: D/dalvikvm(608): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 26 objects / 816 bytes in 48ms
04-30 15:47:01.871: D/AndroidRuntime(608): Shutting down VM
04-30 15:47:01.871: W/dalvikvm(608): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at yadav.sanjay.conv.ConvActivity.click(ConvActivity.java:392)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  ... 11 more
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 15:47:01.891: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  ... 15 more
```

Sorry for not posting the logcat details before.

Comment: Exceptions aren't thrown "during the import" - that's compile-time, this is *execution* time. Please show the details of the exception.

Comment: Check your logcat & attach the entire stack trace of the exception to your question? `InvocationTargetException` is "just" a checked wrapper, and it doesn't tell us much.

Comment: can you paste your logcat details here??

Comment: Added the logcat details

Comment: i think this statement tv2.getText() return null.

Comment: Except that `TextView#getText()` *doesn't* return `null`. Which leaves `tv2` being `null` as the likely culprit.

Comment: Inserted that statement in try block and caught NullPointerException. Still the same Error and on the same line. Also read that InvocationTargetException cannot be caught in try block.

Comment: InvocationTargetException would be hard to catch for you - since it's a wrapper created in response to the exception raised by your code.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the InvocationTargetException, I think it is caused by NullPointerException as shown in logcat. this might be because tv2 is null or tv2.getText() is coming as null. Please check for not null value as

```
if(tv2 != null)
 s=tv2.getText().toString();
else 
 s= "";
```